# Wrong figure and caption position

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I have a problem with my images!!

[image: look at my problem]

As you can see, the position of images (a) and (b) is totally wrong! I don't know why!
I used Latex for a lot of years, but it is the first time I see something like this.
Can anybody help me?

I am using Linux Mint 17 and I use Kile.

The code to generate the images is

```
\begin{figure*} [htbp]
% \centering
\subfigure[\label{fig:adr_MG}]
{\includegraphics[scale=0.29]{ADR_UE_last_1.eps}} 
\hspace{0.2cm}
\subfigure[\label{fig:adr_RB}]
{\includegraphics[scale=0.29]{ADR_RB_last_1.eps}}
\hspace{0.2cm}
\subfigure[\label{fig:adr_TIME}]
{\includegraphics[scale=0.27]{tab_2_new.eps}}
\caption{Aggregate Data Rate as function of the multicast group size (a) and     the number of RBs (b), and execution time comparison (c).}
\label{fig:adr}
\end{figure*}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Looks like you are using `subfigure` package. Use `subfig` instead and its `subfloat` macro. `subfigure` is deprecated.

Comment: Also, have a look at the bounding box of the images. To that end, surround your `\includegraphics` commands with `\fbox`, and see where the box is drawn. It should provide an exterior frame for each image. If it doesn't, you may have to reprocess or manually update the bounding box to be correct.

Comment: It's a baseline problem.  The centers of you graphs are aligned with the bottom of the table (usually it's the other way around).  Must be peculiar to eps files.